# Importing modules with Swift package manager

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to use Swift's package manager to import external modules in my project. My first module come from the [Vapor project](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/json/package/). I cannot seem to get it working. I start with

```
swift package init
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

My Package.swift looks like this:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "OpenTools",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "OpenTools",
            targets: ["OpenTools"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/json.git", from: "2.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "OpenTools", dependencies: ["JSON"]),
    ]
)
```

I then run

```
swift package update
swift package generate-xcodeproj # to regenerate with dependencies
```

and then try to import the JSON package in my main file

```
import JSON
```

The modules are there as shown below but the import gets back with an `No such module 'JSON'` error.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the problem lies within Xcode, as it does not know yet that `JSON` exists, because it was not built yet. This can easily be solved by just building your project (with `cmd-B`). With the generated xcodeproj, Xcode should know that it first needs to build `JSON` and then the rest, because `JSON` is marked as a dependency for your target.
You can check this, by navigating in Xcode to your target (when you click on the project description file) and afterwards to "Build Phases". Under Target Dependencies you should find your `JSON` module.

In addition you should find a `JSON` module under your targets, which compiles the sources you gathered from github.

Your project should also build when executing `swift build` in your project root.

Comment: This is correct. It's just an Xcode quirk. `⌘+B` to build or `⌘+U` to test and you're good to go. Restart Xcode if the error keeps "hanging" and you're good to go.

Comment: Yes, I agree this answer is almost certainly the correct one. So, not a comment

Comment: I have tried this, but it still will not work for me, it even has something in the target dependencies and link with linked binaries sections of the build phases. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 11 you should be able to open `Package.swift` directly which will give you a proving ground for verifying the package manifest (aka: the `Package.swift` file) and compiling the target. This should help see what is actually causing the error that's preventing the module from being compiled.