# Cannot use Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have the latest release versions of Swift and Xcode.

I am trying to use the Swift Package Manager to use this:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/matejkosiarcik/Stopwatch.git", from: "0.1.0")
```

However, I have spent multiple days trying how to figure out how to embed this in my command line tool, or even in a brand new command line tool so that in `Main.swift` it doesn't give the error:

> No such module 'Stopwatch'.

Would someone please explain how to do it for this exact package?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it build? (`⌘+B` in Xcode.)

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268035/importing-modules-with-swift-package-manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the modules in a Swift Package are specified as targets, not as products.

Suppose you have the following product spec in your `Package.swift`:

```
products: [ .library(name: "MyProduct", targets: ["MyTarget1", "MyTarget2"])]
```

Then in some other package you use this product as a dependency in Package.swift:

```
.target(name: "TargetInSomeOtherPackage", dependencies: ["MyProduct"])
```

And in swift code you import modules:

```
import MyTarget1
import MyTarget2
```

In your case, you defined your product: `.library(name: "Stopwatch", targets: ["lib"])`. This means that you can use `Stopwatch` as a dependency, and import module `lib` in your Swift code. There is no module `Stopwatch` that you can import.